# Why is jquery targeting all divs?

Tags: jquery, html

I've implemented a toggle into [a site](http://chloeandmichael.com/#) that toggles more information on click. However, when i click on one it activates all of them.

Something I dont want it to do.

This is what I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){


$(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
</script>


<a href="#" class="show_hide">More Information</a>

<div class="slidingDiv">
.....
</div>
```

Comment: Post a snippet of the HTML here, we don't really want to visit your site and look through all the markup on your site to figure out a solution.

Comment: markup doesn't make sense, can't declare `class` twice in an element...browser will ignore 2 declarations

Comment: ^^^ what he said, and why would both elements have the class that is targeted in the event handler, shouldn't just the anchor have the show_hide class ?

Comment: removed the second class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){


$(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){

$(this).parent().find(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

    });

});
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` instead of `.slidingDiv` in your click handler.

`.slidingDiv` selects all slidingDivs - `this` only selects the element that fired the click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   $(document).ready(function(){


$(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').on('click','.slidingDiv',function(){
    $(this).slideToggle();
    });

}); </script>
```

Comment: that makes the content disappear.

Comment: I've updated it - I didn't realize you wanted to target .slidingDiv and not .show_hide.

Comment: Still won't work, now the event handler is on the wrong element ?

Comment: Go with adeneo's answer - didn't look at the HTML thoroughly enough. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   <a href="#" class="show_hide">More Information</a>
   <div class="slidingDiv" class="show_hide">
```

You're using the class show_hide twice and I think that's why it always shows.